# exception in hi abstraction level methods

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns

A  method performs several tasks:

```
public void method () {

    try {
         task1(); //may throw sql exception
         task2(); //may throw sql exception
         task3(); //may throw sql exception
   } catch (SQLException se) {
       //from which line cames the exception?
   }
```

I'm looking for a criteria to adopt in these situations. 
Currently my idea is this:
1) if i need to take some action depending on the specific line that has thrown the exception, the only thing is surrond each statement with his-own try-catch; three in the example.
2) if i not need to take a specific action based on the line that throws the exception, then the stack trace will give enough information to know line has gone wrong without a try-catch block for each instruction, that makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace will contain all the necessary information.

If you need to take specific actions, then in each `taskX()` method you may want to throw a different exception, wrapping `SQLException`. Same verbosity though.

Comment: and esotic solutions like let each statement be preceded by a "state=1;", "state=2;" etc... When in the error i will know by the state value the last line correctly executed. I try this very effective, its only defect is the handcrafted taste :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a step counter

```
int step = 0;
try {
     task1(); //may throw sql exception
     step=1;//got through first
     task2(); //may throw sql exception
     step=2;
     task3(); //may throw sql exception
} catch (SQLException se) {
   //from which line cames the exception?
   if(step=0){
     //didn't get through first task
   }
   if(step=1){
     //didn't get through second task
   }
   if(step=2){
     //didn't get through third task
   }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much work! StackTrace will show which class the SQL exception generated from so there is no need to keep a separate trace.

Comment: @bozho maybe but the elegant way is very verbose (multi try catches) or requires runtime info about the source code and may break during refactoring or obfuscation (using Throwable.getStackTrace() and matching the strings or linenumbers)

Comment: I personally don't really see the elegance of using a switch statement in a large catch() block instead of using one try/catch per statement. Seems to add quite some complexity and makes refactoring more complicated at the minor win of 2 lines per try (minus lines added by switch)